# Push notification server backend for iOS and Android Interval Poll methods

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, long-polling, polling

I am writing a NodeJS push notification server for iOS and Android. Currently, once I get the device tokens I save them in a local MongoDB database and then fire notifications when there is a change. The problem is, that the database where the "change"(information is added) happens isn't my own. It's a third party's server. So the way I am aware of the change in the server is by using an API provided by the third party. My current solution is using `setTimeout` to make a request every X minutes to check for a change and then firing a notification based on that. The shorted interval is 10 minutes and the longest one is 1 hour. I change the intervals 
dynamically through out the day based on time. My question(s) is (are),

**1.)** **Is the `setTimeout` method the best possible solution to this problem? If not what else can I use?**

**2.) Is there any way I can implement `Web Sockets` in this scenario?**

**3.) If `setTimeout` is the only option, what kind of problems should I expect to run into?**

This what the current function looks like

```
 function start_notifications_server_driver() {
    if(current_user_info.num_sent <= current_user_info.frequency){
       //I removed the interval object on here because it's quite large and would take up space here 
        for(var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++){
            if(check_if_time_between(intervals[i])){
                if(dev_mode) console.log("Returned true for", intervals[i]);
                temp_interval = intervals[i].frequency;
                break;
            }
        }
        check_updates_for_channels_driver();
        setTimeout(start_notifications_server_driver, temp_interval);
        console.log("Time Interval changed to now", temp_interval);
    }
 }
```